# How do I fix this error in Python Django involving request.user.is_authenticated() and bool object not callable?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to make profile pages for each user. I added a code that checks if the user is logged in and does a redirect (see line 12 of the code below).

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

from .models import Account, ForSale, WTB

from mysite.forms import MyRegistrationForm

def signup(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')

        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'signup.html', context)

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

However, upon accessing /signup/ on the site I get the following debug message:

```
TypeError at /signup/
'bool' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://url:8000/signup/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'bool' object is not callable
Exception Location: /www/mysite.com/mysite/views.py in signup, line 13
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
    ['/www/mysite.com',
    '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 3 Dec 2017 18:07:54 -0800
```

Comment: Can you please post the debug message? It looks like you forgot to paste it in.

Comment: I added it (except the trace of stack). If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 11):

In older versions of Django request.user.is_authenticated was a method. It's now an attribute and no longer requires parenthesis. If you change your code to:

`if request.user.is_authenticated:`

It should be work as expected.

For more info see the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Answer (score -2):

you forget to import csrf module please try to add this line and make sure to avoid hardcoded urls try to use url names

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
```